# What happens to a speedster's diet when a power dampener is used on them?

Tags: dc, comics, the-flash-2014

As it's been mentioned on numerous occasions in **The Flash (2014)** TV series and also sometimes in the **Justice League: Animated series**, a speedster needs to consume an insane amount of food just to stay alive due to their increased metabolism.

Does the use of a meta-dampener (or [Meta-power dampening cuffs](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Power-dampening_cuffs)) also affect the diet of a speedster?

Looking for answers/explanations addressing this from everywhere (*TV series, animated series, comics* etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any examples, but since the high metabolism is framed as a consequence of their powers, it would stand to reason that the removal of that power would reduce the need for huge amounts of food and therefore reduce their diet.

Answer (score 0):

Logic would dictate that without the extra energy tax using their power causes on their body, their metabolic rate and thus consumption would drop way down. A similar effect occurs on the human body in real life; as we age and hit puberty, the rapid development on a cellular level calls for more energy...hence why teenagers eat so much. As we grow older  and lose muscle via inactivity, our need for calories decrease.  If we maintain eating to the same extent without compensating via increased activity, it becomes stored as fat.